# Python Wand and ImageMagick on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, imagemagick, aws-lambda, wand

Trying to run Wand on AWS Lambda for some simple image manipulation.

So far I've:

1. created an instance that's identical to lambda environment
2. installed imagemagick from source

   ```
   wget ImageMagick
   cd ImageMagick-...
   ./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/im --without-x
   make && make install
   ```
3. set MAGICK_HOME to `/home/ec2-user/im/`
4. `pip install wand`

but when I try to import wand.image I get:

```
import wand.image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/cv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "/home/ec2-user/cv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 206, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html
```

It works fine when I do a `yum install ImageMagick`, but since I want to bundle it I thought I'd need to include the binary and point the wand installation to it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Were you able to get any resolution to this?  Looks like I'll be going down the same path...

Comment: yep, figured it out, along with a few other libs like opencv, keras, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since someone else is interested now, I solved this issue and currently manage my lambda projects similar to below.

folder structure

```
-project
  -init_libs.py
  -lambda_function.py
  -libs
    -libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
    -libMagickCore-6.Q16.so
    -libMagick++-6.Q16.so
  -site-packages
    -wand
  -other_modules
```

`init_libs.py` loads native libraries like Wand.

```
import sys
import os
from ctypes import cdll
from os.path import join

# manually load libraries and set paths so native libraries can be used.
exec_dir = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(join(exec_dir, 'site-packages'))

# required for Wand
os.environ['MAGICK_HOME'] = exec_dir

lib_dir = join(exec_dir, 'lib')

# add lib to sys path for general loading
sys.path.append(lib_dir)
```

`lambda_function.py` can now import wand

```
from wand.image import Image

print Image
```

Comment: Hey @daxiangCODE, just a quick question, where did you find the shared object files for this fix... I can't seem to locate them

Comment: shoot, this was a while ago on an older project :( it depends on how you installed imagemagick.  look at where your package manager put the files, or try find.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be helpful to the question asked, but if the desired goal is to do some simple file conversion (pdf to jpg/png etc.) one can bypass wand and invoke ImageMagick/GhostScript directly (these are packaged with the Python3.6 AWS environment).

e.g.

```
# converts local pdf to jpg using ImageMagick
os.system("convert -density 200x200 /tmp/in_pdf.pdf /tmp/out_jpg.jpg")

# converts local pdf to jpg using GhostScript
os.system(
        "gs -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT "
        "-dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "
        "-sDEVICE=jpeg -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r150 "
        "-sOutputFile=/tmp/out_jpg-%d.jpg /tmp/in_pdf.pdf"
    )
```

The reason I am using `/tmp` as a file location is because lambda allows you to store files up to 500MB there during the running of the lambda function.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

Inspired from https://gist.github.com/bensie/56f51bc33d4a55e2fc9a#gistcomment-3133859, I was able to successfully package ImageMagick and Ghostscript in a Python 3.8 compatible AWS Lambda layer and use `wand` to convert the pages in a PDF into PNG by following these instructions:

1. Start an EC2 instance and SSH into it. I used the AMI `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210126.0-x86_64-gp2`.
2. Download ImageMagick 6.9.11.

   ```sh
   wget https://download.imagemagick.org/ImageMagick/download/ImageMagick-6.9.11-60.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract the folder.

   ```sh
   tar zxvf ImageMagick-6.9.11-60.tar.gz
   ```
4. `cd` into the extracted folder.

   ```sh
   cd ImageMagick-6.9.11-60
   ```
5. Edit the `policy.xml` file to allow PDF to PNG conversion.

   ```sh
   nano config/policy.xml
   ```

   I copy-pasted the following content but you can modify it as needed.

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE policymap [
   <!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
   <!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
   <!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
   <!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
   <!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
   <!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
   <!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
   ]>
   <!--
     Configure ImageMagick policies.

     Domains include system, delegate, coder, filter, path, or resource.

     Rights include none, read, write, and execute.  Use | to combine them,
     for example: "read | write" to permit read from, or write to, a path.

     Use a glob expression as a pattern.

     Suppose we do not want users to process MPEG video images:

       <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="mpeg:decode" />

     Here we do not want users reading images from HTTP:

       <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />

     Lets prevent users from executing any image filters:

       <policy domain="filter" rights="none" pattern="*" />

     The /repository file system is restricted to read only.  We use a glob
     expression to match all paths that start with /repository:

       <policy domain="path" rights="read" pattern="/repository/*" />

     Let's prevent possible exploits by removing the right to use indirect reads.

       <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*" />

     Any large image is cached to disk rather than memory:

       <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="1GB"/>

     Define arguments for the memory, map, area, width, height, and disk resources
     with SI prefixes (.e.g 100MB).  In addition, resource policies are maximums
     for each instance of ImageMagick (e.g. policy memory limit 1GB, -limit 2GB
     exceeds policy maximum so memory limit is 1GB).
   -->
   <policymap>
     <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/tmp"/> -->
     <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>
     <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="512MiB"/>
     <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="16KP"/>
     <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="16KP"/>
     <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="128MB"/>
     <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="1GiB"/>
     <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="file" value="768"/> -->
     <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/> -->
     <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="0"/> -->
     <!-- <policy domain="resource" name="time" value="3600"/> -->
     <!-- <policy domain="system" name="precision" value="6"/> -->
     <!-- not needed due to the need to use explicitly by mvg: -->
     <!-- <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="MVG" /> -->
     <!-- use curl -->
     <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
     <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
     <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
     <!-- in order to avoid to get image with password text -->
     <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
     <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
     <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
     <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
     <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="EPI" />
     <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />
     <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
     <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="LABEL" />
   </policymap>
   ```
6. Configure and install ImageMagick.

   ```sh
   ./configure --prefix=/var/task/imagemagick --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes --with-modules --with-perl=no --with-x=no --with-gslib=no --with-lcms --without-rsvg --with-xml --without-dps --disable-hdri --with-quantum-depth=8 --disable-openmp
   make
   sudo make install
   ```
7. Copy the required `.so` files.

   ```sh
   mkdir lib
   cd /usr/lib64/
   cp -L libbz2.so.1 libexpat.so.1 libfontconfig.so.1 libfreetype.so.6 libgs.so.9 libjbig.so.2.0 libjpeg.so.62 liblcms2.so.2 liblzma.so.5 libpng15.so.15 libtiff.so.5 libxml2.so.2 libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.6 libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.6 libXext.so.6 libXt.so.6 libltdl.so.7 libSM.so.6 libICE.so.6 libX11.so.6 libgomp.so.1 libuuid.so.1 libxcb.so.1 libXau.so.6 libMagickCore-6.Q8.so.6 libMagickWand-6.Q8.so.6 libm.so.6 libz.so.1 libjasper.so.1 /home/ec2-user/lib/
   cp -r ImageMagick-6.9.10/ ImageMagick-6.9.11/ /home/ec2-user/lib/
   cd /home/ec2-user
   tar zcf lib.tar.gz lib/
   ```

   Copy the `lib.tar.gz` file from the server to your local machine.
8. Copy the required binary files.

   ```sh
   cd /var/task/imagemagick
   sudo tar zcf bin.tar.gz bin/
   cp bin.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/bin.tar.gz
   ```

   Copy the `bin.tar.gz` file from the server to your local machine.
9. Copy the XML files required by ImageMagick.

   ```sh
   cd /etc/
   sudo tar zcf etc.tar.gz ImageMagick-6/
   cp etc.tar.gz /home/ec2-user/etc.tar.gz
   ```

   Copy the `etc.tar.gz` file from the server to your local machine.
10. Close the SSH session.
11. On your local machine, extract the contents of the 3 `*.tar.gz` files.
12. Download ghostscript from https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9533/ghostscript-9.53.3-linux-x86_64.tgz and extract the ghostscript binary into the `bin/` folder and rename it to `gs`. Run `chmod +x bin/gs` to make it executable.
13. Compress the 3 - `lib`, `bin` and `etc` - folders into a ZIP file. The tree structure of the ZIP file would look like

    ```
    file.zip/
    |-- bin
    |   |-- convert
    |   |-- ...
    |   `-- gs
    |-- etc
    |   `-- ImageMagick-6
    |       |-- coder.xml
    |       |-- ...
    |       `-- type.xml
    `-- lib
        |-- ImageMagick-6.9.10
        |   |-- config-Q16
        |   |   `-- configure.xml
        |   `-- modules-Q16
        |       |-- coders
        |       |   |-- aai.la
        |       |   |-- ...
        |       |   `-- yuv.so
        |       `-- filters
        |           |-- analyze.la
        |           `-- analyze.so
        |-- ImageMagick-6.9.11
        |   |-- config-Q8
        |   |   `-- configure.xml
        |   `-- modules-Q8
        |       |-- coders
        |       |   |-- aai.la
        |       |   |-- ...
        |       |   `-- yuv.so
        |       `-- filters
        |           |-- analyze.la
        |           `-- analyze.so
        |-- libICE.so.6
        |-- ...
        `-- libz.so.1
    ```

    I have used `...` wherever the folder contained more than 2 files to denote that there are more files present.
14. Create a Python 3.8 runtime compatible layer on AWS Lambda and use the ZIP created in step 13.
15. Add the layer to your AWS Lambda function.
16. Update the environment variables so that `wand` can find ImageMagick.

    ```py
    import os

    os.environ["PATH"] = f"/opt/bin:{os.environ['PATH']}"
    os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = f"/opt/lib:{os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']}"
    os.environ["MAGICK_HOME"] = "/opt/"
    os.environ["WAND_MAGICK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX"] = "-6.Q8"
    os.environ["MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH"] = "/opt/etc/ImageMagick-6/"
    os.environ["MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH"] = "/opt/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.11/modules-Q8/coders/"
    ```

Note: If the size of the uncompressed ZIP file is too large and you reach AWS Lambda size limits, remove the binaries that you don't need from the `bin/` folder. In my case, I only kept `Magick-config`, `MagickCore-config`, `MagickWand-config`, `Wand-config`, `convert` and `gs` and removed others.

Comment: This helped me. In my case, I created a docker Amazon image and installed ImageMagick-devel. It does not include the ghostscript executable (gs), but instead uses files in /usr/share. A lot of work to get it going on a Lambda, but working now.